# How to Ask a Question

Tags: discussion

While I doubt the people who ask bad question read the help shown on the side when asking a question:

> How to Ask
>
> Is your question about managing information technology systems in a
>   business environment?
>
> Review our list of allowed topics. We prefer questions that can be
>   answered, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.
>
> If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

This help does not actually explains "How to Ask".

I think a little text that explains what "Provide details" means. Or a short "dos and don'ts".

For example https://serverfault.com/questions/662704/changed-the-dns-settigs-a-name-records-a-week-ago-still-resolving-to-old-server

In this post, the person does not provide any data. Sure he wrote some text in his question, but there is no data provided.

I explain:

Data is not a conclusion. In this case, all the person wrote about is the conclusion that *"it still resolves to the old server and not the new server."*

That's not data, but rather a conclusion. He provides some *hints* as to what he might have done: *"I have refreshed the cache, and checked the hosts file for the computer."*

But does it give us data? We don't know what he did to "refreshed the cache" (Firefox cache for all I know since there is not many program that I know of that actually *refreshes* the cache - most *clear* the cache so it can build a new one...).

So I think the "How to Ask" text should at least include a line that reads, in bold:

**Provide details on what you did, exact commands and their results.**

Comment: Whether or not they read it, it might be useful in case we want to link to the page as an explanation as to _why_ their question is bad. For instance "A conclusion is not data." is something I would very much like to reuse in a lot of questions that don't actually show the users process for reaching their conclusions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We already have lots of information to help people ask a better question perhaps they can be linked to in the text of the close reason. For example there is

- A [helpful checklist](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6074/do-you-have-a-checklist-that-can-help-me-ask-a-better-question)
- A [helpful treatise on how to ask a better question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)
- [How to get a better answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/237/how-do-i-get-better-answers) which is all about asking a better question.
- [How to get people to read my question fully](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2177/how-can-i-get-people-to-fully-read-my-question) which again is about how to write a better question.

We can provide close reasons with rich linked text but sadly, no one who needs to ever reads anything. You can lead a horse to water ...